# Magento2 URL key for specified store already exists. while creating product

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3.1, script

- I'm creating products using scripts.
- Product data came from json file.
- Problem is I'm getting error **URL key for specified store already
  exists.** ,when second product has same name but different sku.
- So, second product url should be `url-1.html` if `url.html` is exist.

Is it a Magento bug? How can I solve that?

```
foreach ($files as $etiq) {
  $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
  $_product->setName($name);
  $_product->setSku($Sku);
  $_product->setTypeId('simple');
  .
  .
  .
  .
  $_product->save();
}
```